# XML overwrite previous node

Tags: php, xml

My job has a bulk of xml config file, a tag called  in  node.

Example:

```
<root>
  <pages>
    <page>
      <file_input_folder>\\Trucks\_MANUAL</file_input_folder> 
      <file_input_virtual_dir>MANUAL</file_input_virtual_dir> 
      <file_output_folder>C:\MANUAL</file_output_folder>
      <fields>
       <field>InvoiceNumber</field>
       <field>CustomerNumber</field>
      </fields>
    </page>
    <page>
      <file_input_folder>\\Trucks\_MANUAL</file_input_folder> 
      <file_input_virtual_dir>MANUAL</file_input_virtual_dir> 
      <file_output_folder>C:\Auto</file_output_folder>
      <fields>
       <field>InvoiceNumber</field>
       <field>AutoNumber</field>
      </fields>
    </page>
  </pages>
</root>
```

What I want to archieve is as below, the duplicate element in second page node will automatically load from first page node:

```
<root>
  <pages>
    <page>
      <file_input_folder>\\Trucks\_MANUAL</file_input_folder> 
      <file_input_virtual_dir>MANUAL</file_input_virtual_dir> 
      <file_output_folder>C:\MANUAL</file_output_folder>
      <fields>
       <field>InvoiceNumber</field>
       <field>CustomerNumber</field>
      </fields>
    </page>
    <page>
      <file_output_folder>C:\Auto</file_output_folder>
      <fields>
       <field>AutoNumber</field>
      </fields>
    </page>
  </pages>
</root>
```

My xml file are very big, nearly 2k linesm if above can be done and it can be shrinked to a few hundreds lines.

My environment is php but  welcome any language for example python and .net.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example isn't going to work as it's difficult to know which elements are being replaced (you want `<field>AutoNumber</field>` to replace `<field>CustomerNumber</field>` but leave `<field>InvoiceNumber</field>` alone - how?)

This is probably overkill to what your after, but it was interesting to write anyway.

The way I've solved it is to use a template for any page element, this contains the truly common data and then each page just has the data it has which is extra to the template.

I use an 'id' attribute in each page to identify which page you want the values of and an 'id' attribute to identify the template.  The page uses (if necessary) a 'template' attribute to say which template it uses.  This means you can have several templates if you want.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function mergeElement ( $source, &$dest )   {
    foreach ( $source as $node ) {
        $nodeName = $node->getName();
        // If it's a nested item, go down to next level
        if ( isset( $dest->$nodeName ) && count($node->children()) > 0)    {
            mergeElement($node, $dest->$nodeName);
        }
        else    {
            $dest->addChild( $nodeName, (string)$node);
        }
    }
}

function fetchPage ( $pageName, $source )    {
    $pageData = $source->xpath ( "//pages/page[@id='{$pageName}']");
    // If no page found, exit
    if ( count($pageData) == 0 )    {
        return false;
    }
    $pageData = $pageData[0];
    unset($pageData['id']);
    // If no template - return data as is
    if ( !isset($pageData['template'])) {
        return $pageData;
    }
    $template = $source->xpath ( "//template[@id='{$pageData['template']}']")[0];
    // Add in page to template
    mergeElement ( $template, $pageData );
    // remove template id from XML
    unset($pageData['template']);

    return $pageData;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");

// Fetch the data for 'pageB'
$page = fetchPage ( "pageB", $xml );
echo $page->asXML();
```

Where data.xml contains...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <template id="1">
        <file_input_folder>\\Trucks\_MANUAL</file_input_folder>
        <file_input_virtual_dir>MANUAL</file_input_virtual_dir>
        <fields>
            <field>InvoiceNumber</field>
        </fields>
    </template>
    <pages>
        <page id="pageA" template="1">
            <file_output_folder>C:\MANUAL</file_output_folder>
            <fields>
                <field>CustomerNumber</field>
            </fields>
        </page>
        <page id="pageB" template="1">
            <file_output_folder>C:\Auto</file_output_folder>
            <fields>
                <field>AutoNumber</field>
            </fields>
        </page>
        <page id="pageC">
            <file_output_folder>C:\Auto1</file_output_folder>
            <fields>
                <field>AutoNumber1</field>
            </fields>
        </page>
    </pages>
</root>
```

The above shows the template and how it's linked to the data pages, the last page doesn't use a template and is returned as is.

Which produces as output for 'pageB' (although this is formatted) ...

```
<page>
    <file_output_folder>C:\Auto</file_output_folder>
    <fields>
        <field>AutoNumber</field>
        <field>InvoiceNumber</field>
    </fields>
    <file_input_folder>\\Trucks\_MANUAL</file_input_folder>
    <file_input_virtual_dir>MANUAL</file_input_virtual_dir>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks, brilliant idea and even more flexible. I will give a try